# SQL full documentation

Tags: sql, documentation

I am studying SQL and when I try to solve questions I always keep finding new functions I didn't know about. I've spent quite some time looking for a full SQL documentation. No matter where I look I only get the most used commands. Is there a reason there is no full documentation or did I just miss it?

Thanks

Comment: The full ANSI SQL specification: https://www.iso.org/standard/63556.html. However, it will not be very useful.

Comment: Yes the problem with the ANSI is that it is out of date right? The answer in the linked question is also referring to this documentation but I am looking for something that is useful, or the reason why there isn't?

Comment: No product has implemented the full ANSI SQL specification, all have different subsets, and also different vendor specific extensions.

Comment: The current ANSI SQL version is SQL-2016, and the next version is planned to be published 2021.

Comment: You need to read the manual for the database product you are using. It will contain the full documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot study SQL without taking into account which database is implementing it.

Each database is implementing SQL in a specific way and you cannot find 2 databases  management systems that implement SQL *exactly* the same way: yes most SQL statements will work the same but not all of them.

You need to pick a database and use its reference documentation.